# Adding .xml file into a dnn page

Tags: dotnetnuke

i have a default.aspx page that contains details from link.xml file.The data for the default.aspx page comes from a links.xml file. I want to migrate the default.aspx page to dnn. That is i need to include the data of the .xml file to the dnn page. I tried uploading the .xml file to the file manager and then importing the content to the module but it didn't work.

could you please help me with any module that helps me add the data of the xml to it.or any other way where i can add the data from the xml file.

Comment: You will have to be more specific in order for us to help you. Please supply code samples and be more specific in your description.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple of things to use XML in DNN.

1) Download/install the XML module, then point that module to your XML file.
2) Create a custom module that reads from the XML file.

I personally would go with #2 because building modules can be very easy and great development practice to learn the DNN platform.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.but am using dnn7 evoq edition and the xml module doesn't work in there. is there any other way i can do

Comment: Writing a custom module will likely be necessary. Or, you could use the RazorHost module and write C#/razor code to read/display the XML